# JBOSS EAP 7.2 Domain can't start the default server(server-one,server-two,server-three)

Tags: dns, jboss

I tried to start the default domain of JBOSS EAP 7.2 on CentOS Linux 7 server, using the command: `./domain.sh`

The domain started successfully, but 3 default servers of the domain could not start. I get the following error: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/wJqvS6aA)

How do I fix it? Please advice.
I did the same on localhost and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

increase heap size & MetaspaceSize & Xmx is OK